# Comparing dates in same column based on a condition in SQL / Hive

Tags: sql, date, hive

I have a table with the below schema.

Each person_id can have multiple codes (A,B,C,D etc) associated with them. For each person_id with code 'A' compare the corresponding date to the date of all other codes the person may have and filter out the dates to within 6 months of the date of code 'A'

So take example of the first person_id 30038590555, I want to make sure the date of code B and C are within 6 months of the date of A. Since both are above the 6 month threshold, they should be filtered out.

```
person_id   code    Date
30038590555 B   5/16/2017
30038590555 C   1/9/2019
30038590555 A   1/25/2020
37057397055 A   3/21/2020
38438355555 A   1/25/2020
59385393355 C   7/22/2014
59385393355 A   2/22/2020
44384037555 A   12/21/2019
49384037555 A   3/21/2020
50573409355 D   4/5/2016
50573409355 A   4/6/2016
50573409355 F   4/7/2016
50573409355 G   3/2/2017
50573409355 B   3/7/2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interpreting "within 6 months as being "within 6 months after".  The solution can be adapted if it really means 6 months before or after.

If I understand correctly, you want to keep all "A"s and then all others that are within six months of an A.  Use a conditional running max:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when code = 'A' then date end) over (partition by person_id order by date) as prev_a_date
      from t
     ) t
where code = 'A' or prev_a_date > add_months(date, -6)
```

Comment: Wont there where statement be <code> where code = 'A' or date  > add_months(prev_a_date, -6)  <code> ?

Comment: @kusshal . . . Yes.  That was a typo.